# Replace 'null' values from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I have an AJAX call which gets time (in minutes) from a database. However, if the value fetched from the database is `null`, I want to replace "null" to show "0 minutes". Right now, it doesn't display anything if the time is null.

```
$SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
$(function() {
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_ajax',
    function(data) {
        $("#timePeriod").text(data.timePeriod);
        if (data.timePeriod == null) {
            data.timePeriod = '0';
        }
    });
});
```

This is then displayed in the HTML using the following span tag:

`Average time: <span id="timePeriod"></span> mins`

The `if` statement in my AJAX code doesn't work as intended. It doesn't display anything (not even `null`, although that is what's being returned). How can I properly replace this value so that it displays a '0' when the result is null?

Comment: `if (data.timePeriod == null) {` … then you don't change the text of the span in any special way

Comment: Do you have any methods to update the HTML element with what is returned?

Comment: @JoshAdams All I have is that span tag in the HTML, nothing else

Comment: @Quentin Hmm yes that's the problem I figured was happening, but I'm not sure how to update the span text

Comment: @Sarah — How about doing something to the span inside the if statement?

Comment: `$("#timePeriod").text(!isNaN(+data.timePeriod) ? +data.timePeriod : '0');` likely covers everything. If you also need to update data.timePeriod, just do : `data.timePeriod = !isNaN(+data.timePeriod) ? +data.timePeriod : '0';`, then `$("#timePeriod").text(data.timePeriod);`

Comment: @briosheje Write an answer and I will upvote

Comment: @briosheje same, that first piece of code is what I was looking for! thanks!

Comment: Huh okay, done. That wasn't necessary but whatever, cool. :) I've also added a brief explanation behind the code (necessary to undestand the ternary operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the problem properly (despite I'm not really aware why you are using `data.wait`), it should be as easy as:

```
data.timePeriod = !isNaN(+data.timePeriod) ? +data.timePeriod : '0';
$("#timePeriod").text(data.timePeriod);
```

Explanation:

(Logically) you want to check whether the data you are receiving is valid. It may be null (sure), but it also may hold any other strange value. So, to be 100% sure that the value actually can be parsed, we firstly try to cast it to a number (using the unary operator `+`), then we check whether it's NOT a NaN: `!isNan`, the evaluation will return true if the the result **effectively is a number**.

If it is, it assigns the value to the `data` object, else it assigns `'0'`.

The second line just put the value in the `span` element.

Comment: @Oops, I changed my variable names for the purposes of the question but seems like I missed that one. Fixed it! Thanks again for your answer and I appreciate the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('timePeriod').innerText = +data.timePeriod
```

Using `+` converts to a number, `+null` is already 0.

```js
document.getElementById('timePeriod').innerText = +null
```

```html
Average time: <span id="timePeriod"></span> mins
```

Comment: And if, for whatever reason, `data.timePeriod` cannot be coerced to a number, you have NaN on your page - less than desirable.

Comment: Beat me to it!!

Comment: Also, for obvious security reasons, HTML should not be set programmatically unless absolutely necessary. Not sure why this is getting upvotes.. *shrug*

Comment: How he updates the DOM was a little irrelevant it's just a demo but I changed to innerText. Also I'm assuming the REST response will not contain `timePeriod: "ddhdhdfh"`